# How to use optmi method gradient function?

Tags: r, function, optimization, parameters, distribution

How do I use optim() method's gradient to fit say a $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ to a given set of (x,y) data? I have searched for hours and found no decent explanation. $

I believe the gradient function should return a vector of length three in the above case: the partial derivative of the fit metric with respect to $a$, then with respect to $b$, then with respect to $c$. But I am not sure on how to execute that.

I have the following input for $f(x) = ax^2+bx+c$, is my gradient function correct?

```
{r linewidth=80}
x=c(1:10)
y=c(-0.2499211,-4.6645685,-2.6280750,-2.0146818,1.5632500,0.2043376,2.9151158,  4.0967775,6.8184074,12.5449975)
#find min square distance
my.fit.fun = function(my.par)
{
  sum(sqrt(abs(my.par[1]*x^2+my.par[2]*x+my.par[3]-y^2)))               
}

gradient=function(my.par){
  c(my.par[1]*2,my.par[2],0)
}

optim.out = optim(c(0.2,-4,-5),fn=my.fit.fun, gr=gradient, method = "BFGS")
```

Comment: you do not use `optim` for you should consider `nls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would prefer to use Sum of Squares for the function instead of the absolute value. You could do the following:

```
x <- 1:10
y < c(-0.2499211,-4.6645685,-2.6280750,-2.0146818,1.5632500,0.2043376,2.9151158,  4.0967775,6.8184074,12.5449975)

d <- data.frame(x,y)

fun <- function(par, data){
  y_hat <- data$x^2 * par[1] + data$x * par[2] + par[3]
  sum((data$y - y_hat)^2)
}

optim(c(0.2,-4,-5), fun, data = d)
$par
[1]  0.2531111 -1.3135297 -0.6618520

$value
[1] 17.70251

$counts
function gradient 
     176       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Instead of using `optim`, I would use `nls`. Here you just provide the formula. In this case we would have:

```
nls(y~ a * x^2 + b * x + c, d, c(a=0.2, b=-4, c=-5))
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y ~ a * x^2 + b * x + c
   data: d
      a       b       c 
 0.2532 -1.3147 -0.6579 
 residual sum-of-squares: 17.7

Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 2.816e-08
```

Also why start with `0.2,-4, -5` any prior knowledge? If you use 0,0,0 for example in the optim, you would get the `nls` results

EDIT:

Since you want the BFGS method, you could do:

```
fun <- function(par, data){
  y_hat <- data$x^2 * par[1] + data$x * par[2] + par[3]
  sum((y_hat - data$y)^2)
}

grad <- function(par, data){
  y_hat <-  data$x^2 * par[1] + data$x * par[2] + par[3]
  err <- data$y - y_hat
  -2 * c(sum(err * data$x^2), sum(err * data$x), sum(err))
}
 optim(c(0.2,-4,-5), fun, grad,data = d, method = "BFGS")
$par
[1]  0.2531732 -1.3146636 -0.6579553

$value
[1] 17.70249

$counts
function gradient 
      38        7 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: thank you, and no particular reason but i was testing out for better fit although i have to use gradient with BFGS in this exercise so can you give some pointers on the BFGS gradient? thank you

Comment: can you please explain what the grad you got is? thank you so much for the help

Comment: youre a genius, it worked... i spent hours on figuring gradient part out but i cant so if you could explain that lol

Comment: @jamesblack. I used error sum of square s as the functiom to optimize/ minimize. Now you just do a derivative of that with respect to the parameters. Since I cant write latex on stackoverflow, it will be difficult for me to show the steps. But you can easily see that if you differentiate with respect to a, you get sum(x^2*error). Check out ordinary least squaresminimization.